# Display a message to user for empty user fields

Tags: 8, status-messages

User's have a field called "Location" (uses the Address module).

I would like to show a message (or enable a block) to users that have not filled out this field.

Specifically, this message should be shown when they log in, view their profile, or when they view their dashboard.

I am attempting to do this with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), but no luck yet. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Want to display where exactly? I wouldn't go for Rules. I'd use a preprocess hook maybe. Get current user, get field, if empty send uncached message to desired template.

Comment: Anywhere really. Messages regions works. Just not on the field itself. A message like "Hey, your profile is incomplete. <link to user/edit> to complete your profile."

Comment: The question is too broad, because it depends on exactly when the message should be displayed. The first case is the easiest one, there is a hook_user_login(). The other cases need to be more specific exactly when and how often the message should be triggered. For example if you put the message in a preprocess hook for the profile page it gets triggered only when the profile is changed, otherwise the page is delivered from cache and nothing happens.

Comment: @4k4 – Same with my answer? Also for an authenticated session?

Comment: @leymannx. yes, pages for authenticated users are cached, too. Even with uncacheable blocks on the page, which then get placeholdered and the page is cached without them.

Comment: @4k4 – Shouldn't it work then adding `$variables['page']['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'user';` in preprocess page? To have changes to the user profile bubbling up and get user-dependent cache?

Comment: @leymannx, this works, but is not good for cache performance. Better place a block with this context on the page. Drupal is preconfigured to deliver such blocks through BigPipe.

Comment: @4k4 – Ah yeah, that's nice. Current user from block context and `blockAccess` for visibility? Ah sorry, you mean like prkos' answer. A Views block and user as context. +1! I also added a chapter about adding a content block from the UI and use `hook_block_access` to control visibility. How is that?

Comment: The problem is still that the question is too broad, there are too many possible answers. It's unclear whether this is about messages, which are normally triggered on events or blocks containing the content of the user entity, which also includes the state of a field being empty or not.

Answer (score 4):

This solution may be less performance happy than preprocessing (or not, it's difficult to say depending on caching etc), but I thought I'd be good to throw it out there since it's a "no-code" solution.

1. Create a Views with Block display listing users
2. Filter according to Location field `Is empty` to show only users who don't have it filled in
3. Add a Contextual filter for the user ID and set it to the current user, Hide Views if it doesn't validate
4. Add `Custom text` field and enter your message to be shown
5. Add the `No results behaviour`, this may need some thinking around how to handle the cases when the uses do have the Location field filled in
6. Place the block in as many regions of your theme as you need, and configure each Block visibility so it makes sense for your cases
7. Don't forget to also configure the Block contextual filter settings

Comment: Great no-code solution - works exactly as I'd hoped. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, a block is the best solution for a message always shown, which doesn't depend on an event. When caching is configured correctly you get a block which can be lazy built and delivered by Big Pipe.

Answer (score 2):

Two possible ways I can think of.

First, via a preprocess hook. Maybe [`template_preprocess_page()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/8.2.x) or `*_html` as they are being called on every page request. But you need to ensure to add `user` to the cache contexts to get a user-specific version of the cached page and to have changes to the user profile bubbling up. This works but still might not be good for cache performance, to have every single page cached user-specifically.

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_page().
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {

  // Add the current user to the cache contexts.
  $variables['page']['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'user';

  if (\Drupal::currentUser()->isAuthenticated()) {

    // 1. Get the current user.
    /** @var $user \Drupal\user\UserInterface */
    $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());

    // 2. Check if field exists.
    if ($user->hasField('field_location')) {

      // 3. Get field.
      $location = $user->get('field_location');

      // 4. Check if field is empty.
      if ($location->isEmpty()) {

        // 5. Trigger message.
        \Drupal::messenger()->addMessage('Hello World!');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Second, via a custom block and [`hook_block_access()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_access/8.7.x) implemented from a custom module. Have core's `block_content` (Custom Block) module enabled, add a custom block type (maybe "User Message"), create a custom block, remind its machine name (it's the block ID) and add it to the region you wanna have the message displayed. Then implement the following.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_block_access().
 */
function MYMODULE_block_access(\Drupal\block\Entity\Block $block, $operation, \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface $account) {

  if ($operation == 'view' && $block->id() == 'BLOCK_MACHINE_NAME') {

    if ($account->isAuthenticated()) {

      /** @var $user \Drupal\user\UserInterface */
      $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($account->id());

      if ($user->hasField('field_location')) {

        $location = $user->get('field_location');

        // Hide if location field is not empty anymore.
        return \Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult::forbiddenIf($location->isEmpty() === FALSE)
          ->addCacheableDependency($block);
      }
    }
  }

  return \Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult::neutral();
}
```

Comment: Many thanks! Very useful snippet. I wonder if I can render a block with `\Drupal::entityTypeManager()-> getViewBuilder('block_content')->view($block);` instead of showing a message. Or even start a Tour. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @ymdahi – Uh yes, this is a much better idea! Place a block and then use `hook_block_access` to hide it if the user's location field got filled. Will update my answer later!